# How do I prevent set access to a static property in the derived class?

Tags: c#

```
public abstract class ExeCommand
{
    private static object commandHandler;
    public static object CommandHandler
    {
        get { return commandHandler; }
        set { commandHandler = value; }
    }
}

class ServerCommand : ExeCommand
{
}
```

This is the bare bones of it.
I want to allow

**ExeCommand.CommandHandler = myCommandHandler**

but not

**ServerCommand.CommandHandler = myCommandHandler**

Any way to enforce this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's unclear what you are trying to achieve here.**

You could prevent `ServerCommand.CommandHandler` from being writable by declaring the same property but hiding the setter, as Cory points out, but why? The caller could always just use `ExeCommand.CommandHandler` to assign a value. ServerCommand shares the static members from its base class.

**Perhaps if you could explain what you are trying to achieve a better design could be proposed.**

Comment: It's part of a Command pattern I'm implementing. ExeCommand has CommandText, parameters and an Execute() method which is overridden in derived classes. Eg. ServerCommand will use reflection to Invoke the method using CommandText as the method name. CommandHandler is the class containing those methods held in another namespace. UserCommand is another ExeCommand used in a similar way. It just seems wrong that UserCommand.CommandHandler = myCommandHandler will also affect the command handler of ServerCommand. It seems right to enforce the changing of the property via ExeCommand.

Comment: Perhaps these shouldn't be static properties then?

Answer (score 3):

Both are the same thing. They compile to the same code.

What you are trying to do is pointless.

Sorry for being blunt.

Comment: If the only point of deriving from the base is to limit access then yes. I assumed this was a simplified example and more was going on in the derived class.

Answer (score 2):

Use `new`

```
class ServerCommand : ExeCommand
{
    public new static object CommandHandler
    {
        get { return ExeCommand.CommandHandler; }
    }
}
```

This doesn't entirely solve the problem because you could still cast to ExeCommand which would allow modification.

Update: As others pointed out `base` isn't valid in a static method. Corrected.

Comment: "base" is not legal in a static method. Just name the type explicitly.

Comment: shouldn't that be private/protected?

Comment: it would have to be ExeCommand.CommandHandler (base can't be used with static)

Comment: Thank you, yes but I wondered if you could do it by altering the base class only.